# Plotting time (HMS) with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I'm trying to plot a running sessionsI want to make a ggplot with:
x=distance (2.2KM, 5KM, 10KM , 12.8KM, Ziel)
Y= time (HMS)

I have the following data:

```
'data.frame':   16333 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Numéro  : chr  "6526" "5427" "6528" "6529" ...
 $ X2.2km  : chr  "00:10:47.4" "00:08:58.2" "00:11:10.4" "00:09:27.3" ...
 $ X5km    : chr  "00:26:05.0" "00:21:46.1" "00:27:13.5" "00:22:35.3" ...
 $ X10km   : chr  "00:56:30.1" "00:45:59.3" "00:58:53.1" "00:47:51.7" ...
 $ X12.8km : chr  "01:14:24.7" "00:59:50.7" "01:17:35.0" "01:01:42.6" ...
 $ Zielzeit: chr  "01:37:40.0" "01:16:38.1" "01:41:53.0" "01:19:02.5" ...
```

the next step is to use  **melt** function from library **reshape2** and **lubridate**

```
xx<-melt(xx,id="Numéro")
####Using lubridate ####
xx$value<-hms(xx$value)
```

My problem is here when i try to plot simple graphics, i receive the following message

```
> ggplot(xx,aes(variable,value))+geom_point()
Error in x < range[1] : cannot compare Period to Duration:
 coerce with 'as.numeric' first.
> ggplot(xx,aes(variable,value))+geom_line()
Error in x < range[1] : cannot compare Period to Duration:
 coerce with 'as.numeric' first.)
```

DATASET

```
  xx <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="   
       Numéro variable value
  1    6526   X2.2km 10M 47.4S
  2    5427   X2.2km  8M 58.2S
  3    6528   X2.2km 11M 10.4S
  4    6529   X2.2km  9M 27.3S
  5    6530   X2.2km  8M 29.3S")
```

Thank for any kind of contributions .

Comment: _"My problem"_, what exactly is your problem? Are you getting an error? Or the wrong plot? How, why?

Comment: OK Axeman keep cool please, i will update my question

Comment: Could you clearly explain what kind of graph you are trying to plot ? A scatter/line plot? Which variables do you want on x and y axis? Remember that `variable` is a factor and `value` is of class `Period`.